# picking a fancy word for posts

Tags: wording

We are developing a web application where users can post beautiful magazine-like articles (those are mostly images and an adequate amount of text). Though we don't like words like atricle or post, so we are trying to find or invent a word that is more suitable for us. Right now our best is a "clip", what do you think?  It would be really nice to find one of those funny made up words like "tweet". Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited on http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Arguably yes, though there is a usability issue if the op picks some word his users never use !

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing your audience makes things difficult, but maybe you could call each article a "piece"? e.g. would you like to edit your International Travels piece? Would like to compose a new piece?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an article then call it an article.

It would be less usable to invent a word or pick an obscure word for something that has a common, recognisable name.

You should speak the language your users speak when naming the elements of your application. If they call it an article then you should too. Magazine style articles are well established and the creators will have their own familiar terms for things and this is where your terms should come from.

Twitter popularised a new, web based form of communication and so had some room to use new words so the example is not too relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This really comes down to the tone you are trying to set for your audience.  Different terms evoke different feelings.

A magazine article can also be called a *column*.  This makes me think of classic journalism, bylines, blocky text, huge headlines, newspapers, etc.

Another word you could consider is *piece*.  This seems to me to evoke more of an artistic, considered, deliberate tone.  It also sounds a little bit pretentious.

If each article is mostly images, could you refer to that collection as a *gallery*?  This term makes me think of art galleries and keeps the focus on the images and less on the text that goes along with them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of suggestions. I hope one of them sticks or is useful. I think *Feature* and *Piece* are particularly good.

- Post
- Article
- Contribution
- Item
- Piece
- Work
- Creation
- Column
- Production
- Opus
- Feature

Comment: mmm contribution

Answer (score 0):

Try not to restrict to a single word (provided you have space for a few in button) Try to communicate 1. What is going to happen next 2. How will image be projected outside 3. What will people do in return. Choose the word based on answering these questions. Do not be reluctant of using cliche. You can even use "Spread the word" "Let people read this" "Yes, this is amazing for people to read" - Try to simplify further if space is a restriction